# Toolbar not showing up in Xamarin.Forms (Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, toolbar, toolbaritems

I cannot get to work my toolbar.
I used xaml to define toolbarItems like this:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="Refresh" Priority="0" Text="refresh" Order="Primary" Icon="refresh.png"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs looks like this:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

And in App.xaml.cs :

```
public App ()
    {

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
```

Why toolbar is not showing up?

Comment: Is the toolbar not being shown or the toolbaritem? If it's the toolbaritem, do you for sure have an image in your Android Resource directories with the name "refresh.png"?

Comment: It's the whole toolbar not showing up. The icon is present in the right folder btw